# Who are the 10 strongest fighters in the tournament of power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

The last 10 fighters who lasted are not the strongest because fighters like Hit were knocked out before. Which 10 will be the strongest?

Comment: What are the criteria of being "the strongest"? Otherwise, this looks like an opinion-based question and too broad.

Comment: The Dragon Ball series mainly focuses on power/strength and characters being stronger than each other. Since the question is condensed to 1 series and even focuses on a particular tournament, it is possible to make a list based on the fights that have happened in the series. For example, if A defeats B and B defeats C/ We can conclude A is stronger than B who is stronger than C. @AkiTanaka

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 Your answer indicates that it's *your* ranking, not the official ranking, which in the end will be a popularity voting whether anyone agrees with the answer or not. I'm still not convinced to your reasoning, but I'll let the community decides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A majority of the fighters who lasted until the end happen to be the strongest, however, some characters like *Hit* were indeed knocked out before and didn't last until the end.

I have ranked the characters along with a reason why the character is weaker than the character above him in the list.

1. **Goku**: In his Mastered UI form is the strongest fighter in the tournament of power. He clearly defeated Jiren who admitted defeat in *Episode 130*. If he had the stamina to hold onto the form even longer, he would've knocked out Jiren.
2. **Jiren**: As mentioned above, Jiren lost to Goku in battle in *Episode 130*, so it only makes sense to place him second on the list.
3. **Vegeta**: In his Super Saiyan Blue Evolution form, Vegeta did grow a lot stronger. However, we could see Jiren clearly overwhelm him alongside SSJB+KK*20 Goku and even Android 17 in *Episode 127*. So without a doubt, Vegeta is weaker than Jiren. The only fighter who was able to fight Jiren toe to toe was Goku, hence placing Vegeta third on the list.
4. **Toppo**: As strong as he is, in his God of Destruction form, Toppo is substantially stronger. However, in *Episode 126*, he is clearly overwhelmed and knocked out by Vegeta once Vegeta powers up. Hence it is fair to place him fourth on the list.
5. **Kefla**: **(Note: Assuming Kefla doesn't grow even stronger)** Some might argue Kefla to be stronger than Toppo and some even Vegeta. However, I personally believe Kefla should be placed fifth on the list. The reason is because, Kefla in her SSJ state was shown to be relative to a tired Goku in his SSJB form. The SSJ2 form is a 100 * Base Multiplier. The SSJB form is relative to SSJ Kefla(Possibly even stronger now). The Kaioken*20 would multiply that power 20 times. Hence, Goku in this state would be able to defeat Kefla, if he had the stamina to do so. Toppo was strong enough to initially overwhelm a Super Saiyan Blue Evolution Vegeta who was relative to SSJB+KK*20 Goku. So it makes sense to place Toppo above her on the list
6. **Anilaza**: Again some might argue Anilaza to be stronger than Kefla. However, please note that Anilaza more or less had a relative beam struggle with 3 SSJB Tier characters and Gohan+Android 17, who are between SSJG and SSJB in terms of power. So technically, SSJB Goku+ KK*20 would be way stronger than Anilaza. Kefla in her fully powered state is definitely > SSJB+KK*5 Goku. So it makes sense to place Anilaza below her on the list
7. **Hit**: **(Note: This is a power list. Hit has the skills/technique to possibly even defeat someone stronger than him in terms of power)**In terms of power, I would say Hit is weaker than SSJB Goku and Vegeta. Some might argue Hit was able to fight SSJB+KK*10 Goku in the Universe 6 vs 7 tournaments. However, if you rewatch the fight, Hit used his timeskip and special techniques to avoid getting Hit by Goku's powerful blows and kept striking back. Even during his rematch with Goku, Hit landed several blows on Goku. However, Goku was able to take him out with a single Kamehameha when it managed to land on him. So it makes sense to place Hit below Anilaza.
8. **Android 17**: Based on his performance against Jiren, and managing to survive his attacks(Which even Hit could barely do), I did consider placing him above Hit on the list. However, his inifinite stamina indeed gives him an advantage like Hit has with his technique. So I think it makes sense to place him below Hit on the list considering the fact that he's weaker than SSJB Goku and might very well be weaker than Hit
9. **Gohan:** As strong as he is, Gohan isn't stronger than Android 17. During the pre-tournament arcs, Goku was forced to turn SSJB against Android 17 and only turned SSJB against Gohan when he insisted. Gohan didn't really fight anyone in the tournament who was a lot stronger than him and never really had a chance to improve during the course of the tournament. He indeed got stronger pre-tournament and is very likely between SSJG and SSJB in terms of power, based on his performance against Koicherator, Anilaza and Dyspo. Also based on Gohan's short fight against Toppo alongside Android 17 and Android 17's fight with Toppo, Android 17 seemed to be doing a lot better. So I think it is fair to place him below Android 17 on the list.
10. **Dyspo**:(Note: This is a power list. Dyspo in his super speed mode definitely has the skill to take out stronger opponents). In terms of power, we see Gohan easily outclass Dyspo in *Episode 124* without even powering up further. Hence it is fair to place him below Gohan on the list